# Need to select latest registration by department when joining with person

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Person:**

```
Id  Name
1   Anton
2   Ib
3   Knud
4   Hans
```

**Registration:**

```
Id  PersonId    Status  DateTime        Department
5   1           1       11-1-2013 10:00 1
6   1           0       10-1-2013 09:00 1
7   1           2       10-1-2013 14:05 1
8   1           2       09-1-2013 09:00 1
9   2           2       09-1-2013 09:00 2
10  3           2       09-1-2013 09:00 3
11  4           2       10-1-2013 17:00 1
```

I need to select the latest registration(by person) for the day (10-1-2013) for department 1

**Expected output:**

```
Name    R.Id    P.Id    Status  DateTime        Department

Anton   7       1       2       10-1-2013 14:05 1
Hans    11      4       2       10-1-2013 17:00 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want this:

```
select top 1 p.name, r.id, p.id, r.status, r.datetime, r.department
from registration r join
     person p
     on r.personid = p.personid
where department = 1 and cast(daTetime as date) = '10-1-2013'
order by datetime desc
```

The latest registration by department, not by person.  This just uses a `where` clause to filter by day and department, orders by the `datetime` column and chooses the first one.

To get all of them:

```
select p.name, r.id, p.id, r.status, r.datetime, r.department
from (select r.*, row_number() over (partition by person order by datetime desc) as seqnum
      from registration r
      where department = 1 and cast(daTetime as date) = '10-1-2013'
     ) r join
     person p
     on r.personid = p.personid
where seqnum = 1
order by datetime desc
```

Comment: Gordon Linoff i think there is a problem with your updated version

`select top 1 p.name, r.id, p.id, r.status, r.created, r.departmentid
from checkin r join
     person p
     on r.personid = p.id and r.seqnum = 1
where r.departmentid = '7AF20674-AEC1-4D4C-B1EA-88B1D7E8F3DB' and cast(r.created as date) = '10-1-2013'
order by r.created desc`

Invalid column name 'seqnum'.

Comment: @Andreas . . . You are correct.  `seqnum` was left over from the version where I had misunderstood the question.

Comment: Gordon it wont work with top 1, i have just expanded the example to avoid confusion. It worked if there was only a single registraion to select, but in reality it can be a number of registrations.

Comment: @Andreas . . . LOL, that's back to my original query, basically.